# IONIC Pull to refresh

Tags: ionic-framework

Just try to implement pull to refresh from ionic framework, but it does not work, the icon just keep showing and nothing happen.

Anyone can point where is the problem?

Here is the code.

**lists.html**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Latest Items</h1>
   <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ui-sref="addlist">New</button>
 </ion-header-bar>
 <ion-view title="Terbaru">
  <ion-content>
      <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()">
        pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
      </ion-refresher>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="dash.search" value="" placeholder="Search">
      </label>
      <div class="list card" ng-repeat="x in data" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chat/{{x.id}}">
          <div class="item item-avatar">
             <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{x.photopath}}">
            <h2>{{x.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{x.tgl}}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item item-body">
             <img class="full-image" data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{x.imagepath}}">
            <p>
              {{x.descr}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
              <a href="#" class="subdued right">5 Comments</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', [])

.controller('AddListCategoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var xhr = $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/api/listCat.php'
    });
    xhr.success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data.data;
    });
    $scope.doRefresh = function(){
      $http.get('http://www.mywebsite.com/api/lists.php')
      .success(function(data){
        $scope.data=data.data;
        console.log($scope.data);
      })
      .finally(function(){
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        $scope.$apply()
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add a working plunker?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code. Pulling text should be an attribute of `ion-refresher`.

This is the correct code:

```
<ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()" pulling-text="Pull to refresh...">
</ion-refresher>
```

You added the closing tag before the pulling-text attribute.